# Regex: keep same pattern found multiple times in same line and replace line by appending single pattern in front

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is it possible with notepad++ (or maybe from linux bash shell) to create multiple lines from a pattern found , as many times as the pattern is found and also append single found pattern in the newly created line?

The multi pattern is `val=[0-9]+`
The single pattern is `id=[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Example:

Input lines:

```
id=af2477,val=333,val=777
id=af3456,val=222,val=444,val=678
id=af3327,val=3234,val=123,val=701
```

Output lines:

```
id=af2477,val=333
id=af2477,val=777
id=af3456,val=222
id=af3456,val=444
id=af3456,val=678
id=af3327,val=3234
id=af3327,val=123
id=af3327,val=701
```

I have tried with 2 subgroups but it wont work. It will only replace the second group once:

find what:`(id=[a-zA-Z0-9]+,)(val=[0-9]+,)*`
replace:`\n\1,\2`

UPDATE: Both answers from `Toto` and `Wiktor Stribiżew` seem to do the job. Haven't tested them yet. I would still like to see how this can work with the use of Notepad++ (even if multiple steps are needed)

Comment: You are correct. Updated question.

Comment: It will look more like a hack in Notepad++, with a two regex step solution. `awk` looks a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Since you also consider using Linux tools for this, an `awk` solution looks much more viable:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} /^id=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(,val=[0-9]+)*$/{
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        print $1,$i
    }; next;
}{print $0}' file > outfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/N3erUT).

Here, any line that matches `^id=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(,val=[0-9]+)*$` (i.e. matches the format of the lines you need to expand) is split the way you need with `for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {print $1,$i}; next;`. Else, the line is written as is (`print $0`).

The `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` part sets the input and output field separator to a comma.

Comment: FYI: The above can also be written in 1 line: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} /^id=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(,val=[0-9]+)*$/{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) { print $1,$i }; next; }{ print $0 }' file > outfile`

Answer (score 1):

This perl one-liner does the job (output on STDOUT):

```
perl -anE '($id,$vals)=/(id=\w+),(.+)$/;say "$id,$_" for split/,/,$vals' file
id=af2477,val=333
id=af2477,val=777
id=af3456,val=222
id=af3456,val=444
id=af3456,val=678
id=af3327,val=3234
id=af3327,val=123
id=af3327,val=701
```

**Explanation:**

```
($id,$vals)=/(id=\w+),(.+)$/;       # explode id and values for each line in input file
say "$id,$_" for split/,/,$vals     # print id and each value
```

You can redirect the output to another file:

```
perl -anE '($id,$vals)=/(id=\w+),(.+)$/;say "$id,$_" for split/,/,$vals' file > outputfile
```

Or do the change in-place:

```
perl -i -anE '($id,$vals)=/(id=\w+),(.+)$/;say "$id,$_" for split/,/,$vals' file
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yet very complex to do that with one regular expression for which you are gonna have to use `(?R)` and conditional statements.

---

With multiple steps would be pretty simple. You can for instance do find and replace using the max number of `val` that you might have in the longest lines, such as, imagine 4 would be the largest number of `val`, then we'll have four of `(,val=[^\r\n,]*)` in our initial expression:

```
^(id=[^\r\n,]*)(,val=[^\r\n,]*)(,val=[^\r\n,]*)(,val=[^\r\n,]*)(,val=[^\r\n,]*)$
```

and replace that with four lines,

```
$1$2\n$1$3\n$1$4\n$1$5
 ---- ---- ---- ----
```

#### [Demo for Step 1](https://regex101.com/r/VvzyOk/1/)

For any additional step, we can simply remove one `val` and one line from the end of initial expression and replacement. For example, our expression would look like

```
^(id=[^\r\n,]*)(,val=[^\r\n,]*)(,val=[^\r\n,]*)(,val=[^\r\n,]*)$
```

in the second step, for which we'd replace it with:

```
$1$2\n$1$3\n$1$4
----  ----  ----
```

#### [Demo for Step 2](https://regex101.com/r/ztZCSy/1/)

In the third and final step, our expression has two vals,

```
^(id=[^\r\n,]*)(,val=[^\r\n,]*)(,val=[^\r\n,]*)$
```

and our replacement will have two lines:

```
$1$2\n$1$3
----  ----
```

#### [Demo for Step 3](https://regex101.com/r/9d2SuM/1/)

---

For the case exampled in the question, only two steps are required and the second and third expressions would likely work just fine.